# testing tailwindcss in DevTools

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, tailwind-css

I'm having problems testing tailwindcss in DevTools, when i try to uncheck or unselect display: flex it will uncheck ALL display flexes from everywhere, as you can see i have chosen a div which has display flex and background color, when i uncheck that display flex it will uncheck all display flexes if there are any BUT if i uncheck that background color it will only affect on that div because i dont have background color elsewhere. I dont have that problem with normal css, am i doing something wrong ?

[image]

one workaround is if i delete it from here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .cls and toggle the classes at will.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/#classes

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `display: flex;` that is inside the `.flex` class will disable the `flex display` for all elements that use the `.flex` class.

My suggestion is to remove the `flex` class from the element using JavaScript.

Alternatively, you can remove it using DevTools to debug the issue by modifying the HTML.

**Exemple code:**

```
const element = document.querySelector('#element-id');
element.classList.remove('flex');
```

Comment: why cant it just disable that flex on that specific div ? like css

Comment: @walee It's the same in CSS. Tailwindcss uses a class named 'flex' whose defintion is display: flex. And if you remove that definition, it will affect every div which uses that class. It's same as CSS actually. The best workaround is already mentioned by you in the question

Comment: @AB7zz why i'm not able to edit my own question ? it says There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.

Comment: @walee Another way  to modify the CSS from the DevTools is to go to the 'element.style' class and set 'display: none'.